# Inject Angular Service in Library Using String

Tags: angular

I have the following layout in my Angular application:

```
ServiceA implements KnownInterface {
}

ServiceB implements KnownInterface {
}
```

In the app.module provide section these are provided by means of the provide statement, this has been also tried in router module, but with no success:

```
{ provide: SERVICE_A, useClass: ServiceA},

{ provide: SERVICE_B, useClass: ServiceB}
```

Finally SERVICE_A is defined as an injection token:

```
export const SERVICE_A = new InjectionToken<any>('ServiceA',
  {providedIn: 'root', factory: () => ServiceA} );
```

What I need to do is inject the correct service, or the selected service in an angular library by means of the string parameter: 'ServiceA' or 'ServiceB'. Note this is in a library and so does NOT have direct access to ServiceA or B, so cannot be imported. I have also tried with/without the providedIn to no success either. It does know about KnownInterface though.

```
this.service = this.injector.get<any>>(token);
```

or

```
this.service = this.injector.get<KnownService>(token);
```

However none of these work, and I always get the usual Injection error. NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken ServiceA!
What is the correct way of doing this and can it be done by just providing the string token?
When I request the service in the app part of the code, it works fine.

Comment: Create InjectionToken in the library with certain interface. Then import in the App this token and provide the service.

Comment: @AntonMarinenko and if the application wanted to swap between ServiceA and ServiceB what would the provide look like? I can certainly try and experiment with this approach.

Comment: Angular does not support Injection with interface, so you need to provide the correct injection token. Maybe the injection token you use is not the same as the library use. You should go check for the library source code to figure it out.

Comment: you could have something like `{provide:SERVICE_A,...}, {provide: TOKEN_DEFINED_IN_LIBRARY_AND_USED_IN_LIBRARY, useExisting: SERVICE_A}`.

Comment: @PeterS you need this `{provide: TOKEN_IMPORTED_FROM_THE_LIBRARY, useClass: SERVICE_A}`

Comment: also token can be a string, but for what's purpose

Comment: @AntonMarinenko and others, many thanks for your help, please see my final solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the problem was a mix of the suggestions and some further research. Initially I was providing the services via a data area in the router. Whilst that is "ok", it's not too programmatic. My solution is to provide a resolver via the token method suggested. So my complete solution is:

In the library module, add a forRoot:

```
  static forRoot(service: any): ModuleWithProviders<MyModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [{provide: SERVICE_RESOLVER_TOKEN, useValue: service}]
    };
  }
```

The resolver token is defined in THIS library and is follows:

```
export interface MyResolverInf {
  performServiceResolution(serviceName: string);
}
export const SERVICE_RESOLVER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('ServiceResolver');
```

Define this in a new file in the library module. In the application we can now add the for root call in the imports:

```
MyModule.forRoot(serviceResolver)
```

And then finally in the module instantiate a resolve which points to the correct injection token:

```
export const serviceResolver = new BespokeResolver();
```

The service resolve must implement the interface of course:

```
export class BespokeResolver implements MyResolverInf {

  performServiceResolution(serviceName: string) {
    return resolveService(serviceName)
  }
}
```

The library service now can inject the service resolve and use it.

```
@Optional() @Inject(SERVICE_RESOLVER_TOKEN) private serviceResolver: MyResolverInf)
```

The services are correctly served by name.

Thanks to the following for pushing me towards this solution:

Anton Marinenko
maheryhaja
Andrei